# Absolute div placed on top of div

Tags: html, css

I'll do my best to explain the issue. I created a fiddle with the code. https://jsfiddle.net/caoz7sn2/

I'm trying to place a div on top of a div which I accomplished, but the issue is when you resize the screen, the div with the `position:absolute` doesn't move relatively with the others which is obvious because it's set absolute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>404Vanity</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.svg">

        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="work">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="vision">Vision</a> </li>
                <li><a href="contact">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="goldbar"></div>
    </div>




    <div class="itemList">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/shopashop.png">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="title"><h2>Shopashop</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the `div class="itemList"` is suppose to be placed exactly on top of the goldbar div.

Comment: Is anything preventing you from placing the `.itemlist` inside `.goldbar`?

Comment: Maybe I am missing your point, but why don't you simply set the background color to `.itemlist` to gold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is exactly what your going for. But the reason that the divs aren't lining up right is because the gold bar has that margin: 0 auto. That's telling it to always remain centered on the page.

Then you have your .itemlist, which is being told to be positioned 30% from the left of the page at all times, regardless of browser width.

If your trying to center your itemlist, I would do`left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;` on the absolute elements.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/caoz7sn2/2/